# Hosted WCF POST Service not working

Tags: c#, wcf, post

IService

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                      RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
                      )]
        string SampleMethod(string UserID, string SID, string TypeID);
```

---

Application

```
$.ajax({
                url: serviceurl,
                data: '{UserID:  12345, SID: 23123 ,TypeID: 123123}',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(JSON.parse(data.d), function (id, obj) {
                        alert(obj.Msg);
                    });
                }
            });
```

I have used above code(prototype) for wcf POST service and hosted on IIS 7.0+

I am unable to call this service using ajaxcallback. I have tried the same CODE with GET method, and Hosted on IIS. It works perfectly fine. Where I am going wrong with POST method?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Adding more information about Wrapped and Bare Requests.

There are two issues in your code. The first one is that you use WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest and try to pass the values like a Bare Request. You can change the Message body style as follows.

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

Second issue is that your JSON code that is posting the data is not correct. It should be like below. (Note the quotes for the keys)

```
 data: '{"UserID": 12345, "SID":23123,"TypeID":123123}'
```

The following link outlines the differences between a Bare and a Wrapped request.
http://www.wcf.dotnetarchives.com/2013/12/difference-between-webmessagebodystylew.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Error: The body style 'Bare' is not supported by 'WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. Change the body style to be 'WrappedRequest'.

Some changes will be there in Web.config- I think

Comment: You cannot use a Bare Request with Web Script enabled. Have a look at the comments section for a similiar issue by Rick Strahl here. http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Oct/04/WCF-and-JSON-Services